# Scala: How can I use a count function for multiple letters

Tags: string, scala, count

Ok so I'm trying to check the number of occurrences of a, b and c in a string and I'm trying to use a count function to do. Can I use that with multiple letters?

Answer (score 9):

You can use scala Set

```
  val inSet = Set('a', 'b', 'c')
  "cat".count(inSet)
```

Scala `Set` has `apply` method with same behavior as `contains`, so when you do `count(inSet)` effectively you are doing `count(c => inSet.apply(c))` which is equal to `count(c => inSet.contains(c))`

Answer (score 0):

For each character, just check if this character is inside your list of interesting characters or not,

```
"cat".count( ( c: Char ) => List( 'a', 'b', 'c').contains( c ) )
```